# Drag and Drop or Select files using Type Script/Angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular8

How to use ng-upload-file plugin using typescript:

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

I tired the same but it's not working, any working sample for the same. or any other plugin that has drag and drop/select files functionality and open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a plugin i.e angular-file:

https://github.com/ackerapple/angular-file

for the same and using it.

Thanks